# jQuery 1.5 How to find and replace 2 cells in a table with a new table row cell?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, dom-traversal

I have a table similar to the following.

```
<table class="schedule-table" cellspacing="1" border="0" style="width:100%;">  
  <tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_1">  
    <td class="resource" style="display:none;">8</td>  
    <td class="resource">John Smith</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
  </tr>   
  <tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_2">       
    <td class="resource" style="display:none;">9</td>  
    <td class="resource">Huck Fin</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
  </tr>   
  <tr class="DataRow" id="DataRow_3">  
    <td class="resource" style="display:none;">10</td>  
    <td class="resource">Tom Sawyer</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
    <td class="resource">blah blah blah</td>  
  </tr>   
</table>
```

I'd like to select #DataRow_2 and replace the 4th and 5th cells with :

```
var newTd = <td class="newclass" colspan="2">Stuff for cell that should span two cells</td>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $row = $("#DataRow_2").find(".resource");
   $($row[4]).remove();
   $($row[3]).replaceWith($("<td class='newclass' colspan='2'>Stuff for cell</td>"));
});
```

I assume you have a broader use case so you'll want to make a function and pass in the cells to remove, replace, etc.

You can play with the JSfiddle here:[http://jsfiddle.net/UV2Ce/](http://jsfiddle.net/UV2Ce/1/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var $dt=$('#DataRow_2');
$('td', $dt).slice(-2).remove();
$dt.append('<td class="newclass" colspan="2">Stuff for cell that should span two cells</td>');
```

**First line:**
Saves a jQuery object containing #DataRow_2. We will use this later.

**Second line:**
Searches for tds in the context of #DataRow_2, slicing only the last two ones (4., 5.) and removing them.

**Third line:**
Appends the new td to #DataRow_2

**UPDATE**: If you need to cut off different cells, please refer to the [slice() Manual Page](http://api.jquery.com/slice/). `slice(-2)` will get the last two elements, if you need explicitly the 4. and 5. you can write `slice(3,5)`.

Comment: thanks for your input. I don't think this would quite work as there are 6 cells total (one is hidden) and I want to leave the last cell as it is. This is just a sample. In my real application table, each cell represents a days in a month and I need to be able to find and replace cells that span one or more days and leave the remaining cells in the row untouched

Comment: I used this solution, because it is easy to tweak. See my Update.

Answer (score 2):

As [simple as this](http://jsfiddle.net/GGZTs/):

```
$('#DataRow_2 td:gt(3)')
    .wrapAll('<td class="newclass" colspan="2">Stuff for cell that should span two cells</td>')
    .remove();
```

Comment: +1 nice one :) Tomorrow I will come back and upvote, already used up my daily vote limit :).

Answer (score 1):

Can simply be done in one line:

```
$("#DataRow_2").find("td:gt(3)").remove().end().append(newTd);
```

Query for the row, and then find any td greater [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) than index 3.  Call `end()` to get back to the initial query of `#DataRow_2` and than append your `<td/>` to that row.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Dhm9h/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var newTd = <td class="newclass" colspan="2">Stuff for cell</td>

jQuery('#DataRow_2').find('td:last').remove().end().find('td:last').replaceWith(newTd);
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I think you are saying to remove the last <td>, start over again and replace the new last <td> with newTd? If so, I would lose the content of the original last <td>

Comment: @Bengal: You have never mentioned in your question that you need to keep the original ones :).

Answer (score 0):

Use either the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.

Comment: I am new to jQuery... any chance you could provide a sample?  I started with $("#DataRow_2").find('td').eq(3).remove() but not sure how to complete it

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a bad guy, did you read the documentation Mike linked? I landed on this page just now and Mike's answer helped me quite a bit.

Comment: @Tass - Glad you found it useful. You know what they say: you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him read the manual.